# Devstack listing s3 bucket error "The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, openstack, devstack

I followed the installation guide for Devstack according to this https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/ and then followed this to configure the keystoneauth middleware https://docs.openstack.org/swift/latest/overview_auth.html#keystone-auth
But when I tried to list bucket using boto3 with credentials I generate from OpenStack ec2 credential create, I got the error "The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records"
Would appreciate any help

My boto3 code is

```
import boto3 s3 = boto3.resource('s3',aws_access_key_id='5d14869948294bb48f9bfe684b8892ca',aws_secret_access_key='ffcbcec69fb54622a0185a5848d7d0d2',) 

for bucket in s3.objects.all():
    print(bucket)
```

Where the 2 keys are according to below:

```
| access     | 5d14869948294bb48f9bfe684b8892ca| 
| links      | {'self': '10.180.205.202/identity/v3/users/…'} | 
| project_id | c128ad4f9a154a04832e41a43756f47d |
| secret     | ffcbcec69fb54622a0185a5848d7d0d2 |
| trust_id   | None |
| user_id    | 2abd57c56867482ca6cae5a9a2afda29
```

After running the commands @larsks provided, I got `public: http://10.180.205.202:8080/v1/AUTH_ed6bbefe5ab44f32b4891fc5e3e55f1f` for my swift endpoint. And just making sure, my ec2 credential is under the user admin and also project admin.

When I followed the Boto3 code and removed everything starting from v1 for my endpoint I got the error `botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred () when calling the ListBuckets operation:`

And when I kept the AUTH part, I got `botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (412) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Precondition Failed`

The previous problem is resolved by adding `enable_service s3api` in the local.conf and stack again. This is likely because OpenStack needs to know it's using s3api, from the documentation it says `Swift will be configured to act as a S3 endpoint for Keystone so effectively replacing the nova-objectstore.`

Comment: Can you share with us your `boto3` code? And perhaps also sufficient output from `openstack ec2 credential list` to demonstrate that the access key and secret you're using match values available from openstack.

Comment: My boto3 code is:
`import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3',aws_access_key_id='',was_secret_access_key='',)
for bucket in s3.objects.all():
          print(bucket)`
where the 2 keys are according to below:
| access   | 5d14869948294bb48f9bfe684b8892ca| 
links   | {'self': 'http://10.180.205.202/identity/v3/users/2abd57c56867482ca6cae5a9a2afda29/credentials/OS-EC2/5d14869948294bb48f9bfe684b8892ca'} |
| project_id | c128ad4f9a154a04832e41a43756f47d
| secret   | ffcbcec69fb54622a0185a5848d7d0d2
| trust_id  | None 
| user_id  | 2abd57c56867482ca6cae5a9a2afda29

Comment: When people ask for additional information, you should in general *update the question*, because code posted in comments is just about unreadable.

Comment: sry about that, I will also post my update to the original question. Thx for the guide

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably that nowhere are you telling `boto3` how to connect to your OpenStack environment, so by default it is trying to connect to Amazon's S3 service (in your example you're also not passing in your access key and secret key, but I'm assuming this was just a typo when creating your example).

If you want to connect to the OpenStack object storage service, you'll need to first get the endpoint for that service from the catalog. You can get this from the command line by running `openstack catalog list`; you can also retrieve it programatically if you make use of the `openstack` Python module.

You can just inspect the output of `openstack catalog list` and look for the `swift` service, or you can parse it out using e.g. `jq`:

```
$ openstack catalog list -f json |
  jq -r '.[]|select(.Name == "swift")|.Endpoints[]|select(.interface == "public")|.url'
https://someurl.example.com/swift/v1
```

In any case, you need to pass the endpoint to `boto3`:

```
>>> import boto3
>>> session = boto3.session.Session()
>>> s3 = session.client(service_name='s3',
... aws_access_key_id='access_key_id_goes_here',
... aws_secret_access_key='secret_key_goes_here',
... endpoint_url='endpoint_url_goes_here')
>>> s3.list_buckets()
{'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'tx0000000000000000d6a8c-0060de01e2-cff1383c-default', 'HostId': '', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'x-amz-request-id': 'tx0000000000000000d6a8c-0060de01e2-cff1383c-default', 'content-type': 'application/xml', 'date': 'Thu, 01 Jul 2021 17:56:51 GMT', 'connection': 'close', 'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=16000000; includeSubDomains; preload;'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}, 'Buckets': [{'Name': 'larstest', 'CreationDate': datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 5, 0, 20, 19, 4000, tzinfo=tzutc())}, {'Name': 'larstest2', 'CreationDate': datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 7, 21, 4, 12, 628000, tzinfo=tzutc())}, {'Name': 'larstest4', 'CreationDate': datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 12, 18, 47, 54, 510000, tzinfo=tzutc())}], 'Owner': {'DisplayName': 'lars', 'ID': '4bb09e3a56cd451b9d260ad6c111fd96'}}
>>>
```

Note that if the endpoint url from `openstack catalog list` includes a version (e.g., `.../v1`), you will probably want to drop that.

Comment: Thank you so much, my Devstack environment works now!